# Nonblocking background excel file imports, while Puppeteer continues scraping files

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, puppeteer

### Goals

Using NodeJS and puppeteer, download ~150 excel files every 5 minutes and import them into a database. Optimization is needed to decrease current time down from 15 minutes.

.XLS files are currently uploaded to an S3 bucket and then all S3 paths are passed to another function that reads each file and imports them into PostgreSQL. I am looking at ways to import the excel files after each has completed in the background while puppeteer continues the download of the rest of the files. Concurrently importing and downloading the files. Currently on an AWS t3.medium with two cores.

**Issues**

I have tried using an async callback in the middle of the puppeteer script, but was having a weird issue where it appears that calling the callback for the next file was cancelling the first callback. Is this typical behavior? I couldn't find anything in my searches that might explain why.

```
const { pdmPaths, pickups } = await pdm.getReports(saveDeliveryDetails, savePickupDetails, db);
// if (pdmPaths.length > 0) {
//   // eslint-disable-next-line no-restricted-syntax
//   for await (const path of pdmPaths) {
//     await saveDeliveryDetails(db, path);
//   }
// }
// if (pickups) await savePickupDetails(db, pickups);
console.log('\n Finished Importing Manifest data \n');

await s3.putObject(path, readFileSync('./downloads/P&DDetails.xls'));
unlinkSync('./downloads/P&DDetails.xls');
pddPaths.push(path);
await savePnDCallback(db, path);
```

Replace path array return with callback

```
await s3.putObject(path, readFileSync('./downloads/P&DDetails.xls'));
unlinkSync('./downloads/P&DDetails.xls');
pddPaths.push(path);
await savePnDCallback(db, path);
```

Instead of saving all downloads and then passing the S3 paths to the import function after puppeteer finished, I tried using an async callback (without await) and had weird side effects where the callback function would just stop with no error. I believe when the same function was being called by the next download, it would stop the previous callback. I may be attempting the solve the problem completely wrong. I'm now awaiting the callbacks, but this is causing even more time to complete the the original version doing each in batches.

**Possible Solutions**
I could use a lambda function that triggers on s3 upload to import into the database. I'm not sure about the speed, or cost of this approach as I have no experience with Lambda yet. This could be a better solution if the EC2 instance can't handle both operations at once.

Determine if callback issue is a lack of understanding of how callbacks work, or an issue with the implementation.

Determine if some extra work is needed to utilize the other CPU thread of the t3.medium instance.